# Ip route : access ip on different interface trough Wireguard VPN

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, routing, iptables

I would like to access from my Windows PC a KNX interface that is wired to a Linux PC trought my wireguard VPN but the interface is on a different subnet. The KNX interface use UDP protocol on port 3671. See image below :

My current network:

[image: My current network]

I have already set the ipv4.forwarding and tried to add a route with this :

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 10.0.0.4 --dport 3671 -j DNAT --to 10.10.6.158:3671
```

I added this rule too to the linux iptables : `-A FORWARD -d 10.10.6.158/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 3671 -j ACCEPT \`

I tried to connect to my interface with my KNX software but I get no response. I only have basic understanding of route networking and don't know any tool that could help me solve this.

Comment: Do you want a route or do you want NAT? Those are different things.

Comment: @mashuptwice Since the interface need to send me packets back, I think that a route is more suitable for my needs.

Comment: Well, both the router your windows PC is connected to as well as the KNX device have the same subnet. You'll need to change one of them to use a different subnet than 10.10.6.0, otherwise a route will not work.

Comment: I thought about this, until today I only tried to add route in the Linux PC but it seems now clear that I need a route in my Windows PC too, am I right ?  I'll change the subnet of eth0 and the KNX interface to 192.168.1.0

Comment: Yes, you'll need a route on every hop between the sender and receiver. `traceroute` or `mtr` can be a great help when identifying missing routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the problem, I added the subnet of my interface (10.10.6.0/24) to the client (the Linux PC) AllowedIps of the wireguard server configuration file.
Doing this will result in wireguard itself creating the route in my VPN server.

I then created one route in my Windows PC with the command : `route add 10.10.6.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 10.0.0.4`

My Windows PC was on another subnet (10.10.10.0) to avoid conflict or I should have changed the eth0 and KNX interface subnet to something not already used in my network but that was not doable in my case.